# Are n^2 string expansions created at max when performing fuzzy queries in Elasticsearch/Lucene?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I'm using Elasticsearch with Kibana via docker-compose file (it can be found below).
I'm using their sample [data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.13/get-started.html#gs-get-data-into-kibana).

I'm performing a fuzzy query on a text field `email` with the aim to match the following string: `eddie@underwood-family.zzz`:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "email": {
        "value": "eddie@underwood-family.xzzzy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I get 1 hit with the document whose `email` is indeed `eddie@underwood-family.zzz`. According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html#fuzzy-query-field-params) the search query is expanded with the default number of 50 `max_expansions`. As far as I understand at max 50 strings are created based on my input string `eddie@underwood-family.xzzzy`.

However, as far as I understand for string of length `n` there can be at max `n^2` expansions according to a [dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Iterative_with_full_matrix) (for my input string of 28 characters there would be at max 784 expansions). So I don't understand why my search query yields hits because 784 is much greater than 50. So is it by luck that one of the 50 expansions happened to yield or result or I'm misunderstanding something about how fuzzy queries work?

I should also mention that Lucene [uses](https://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html) Levenshtein Automaton to perform fuzzy search but then why do expansions need to be created at all? A search string should just be provided to the automaton which should return a match or not.

Docker compose file:

```yaml
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.2
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - 'ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.13.2
    container_name: kib01
    depends_on:
      - es01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es01:9200"]'
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Not an answer, because I don't know enough about the internals of `max_expansions`, but... No, these are not something which are generated up-front in the way you were wondering. All matching happens using the distance algorithm you refer to (actually, the Damerau–Levenshtein distance, I think). Expansions are used to limit the number of _positive_ matches found for each fuzzy term in a fuzzy query - thus helping to prevent excessively costly/slow queries. (Referring to these as "expansions" probably makes sense to someone who studies these algorithms & processes more than I do).

Comment: But, yes, that does mean it is possible that your expected e-mail match could fail to be reported as a hit - it's just that your data would have to contain over 50 other (different!) email addresses which also match the fuzzy query in preference to the one e-mail address you expect to see. That would have to be some very unusual e-mail data, for that to happen. I demonstrated that to myself by generating some data meeting those criteria, just as a test.

Comment: @andrewjames I think I got it: `max_expansions` means how many unique matched to return in the query result and sets the value of `hits.total.value` field in the response. The definition from elastic [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html#fuzzy-query-field-params) is really confusing: `max_expansions: Maximum number of variations created. Defaults to 50.` You should post an answer with this explanation and I'll accept it.